# ReferenceError: Contact is not defined error in jquery on debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code snippet that i am trying to use in my Jquery mobile application but i am not able to use that code because of error `ReferenceError: Contact is not defined` that i am seeing on debugging the code on browser..I have not idea why is this error coming ..
Here is the jquery code ..

```
if (typeof Contact === "undefined") {
    getElement("contacts_list").innerHTML = "<p>The Cordova Contacts API is inaccessible</p>";
}
```

On Debugging and seeing a watch at `Contact` i am getting `ReferenceError: Contact is not defined`.

Please help me to resolve this issue..Thanks..

Comment: where you defined the `Contact`, show the code

Comment: this seems to be an issue of scope. you are accessing a variable which is not available somehow.

Comment: @Saqueib If i define this `Contact` as `Var Contact` in my first Js page ..Will it be OK

Comment: @sanatanmishra It should be in scope

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check if a variable is defined in that way. You can do it with a trick:

```
var Contact = Contact || "some_default_value";
if (Contact === "some_default_value") {
    getElement("contacts_list").innerHTML = "<p>The Cordova Contacts API is inaccessible</p>"; 
}
```

`"some_default_value"` must be a value, `Contact` will never have.